# The usage of "according to my gospel" in Paul's writings

Tags: pauline-epistles

> In the day when God shall judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ
> **according to my gospel**. (Rom. 2:16, KJV)
>
> Remember that Jesus Christ of the seed of David was raised from the
> dead **according to my gospel**. (2nd Tim. 2:8, KJV)

I am a bit puzzled by the usage of "according to my gospel" in these verses. It sounds as if God were going to judge the secrets of men in the future because apostle Paul is preaching so, and as if Jesus was raised in the past solely because Paul had preached so -- as if the apostle were placing his gospel above the God's deeds that took place in the past and that are to take place in the future.

Of course, if we take into consideration Paul's attitude throughout all his epistles, we'll see that this is not the case. But then why not say something more humble like "which is what my gospel is about" or "which my gospel corresponds to"?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of "according to", which is the same as the two phrases you wrote. Try asking reading and searching for the meaning of "according" or post a question in English Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

You might be over-thinking this one.

Paul uses the word *my* to emphasize the difference between his calling to preach the gospel to the uncircumcised and (say) the apostle Peter's calling to preach the gospel to the circumcised.

Paul was destined from birth to be the first apostle to be called by God to preach the gospel to the Gentiles. That was the ministry God entrusted to him. The content of the gospel, whether to Jews or Gentiles, was the same for both audiences. Generally speaking, however, the Jews who became followers of Jesus Christ did not imagine non-Jews as even being worthy of the gospel, as Peter demonstrated so well in Acts Chapter 10.

So entrenched was Peter in believing Gentiles were "unclean," God had to give him the same vision ***three*** times! He finally got the message, and he received the attitude adjustment he so desperately needed. He went from saying "Not so, Lord," to "I should not call anyone impure or unclean."

In short, then, "Paul's gospel" did not *belong* to him; it was part and parcel of his ministry to his primary audience, the Gentiles. Furthermore, until the believing Jews, including Peter, caught up with God, so to speak, and were on the same page as God regarding the Gentiles, Paul would find himself defending his ministry and its message--the gospel--that in Christ

> there is neither Jew nor Gentile, neither slave nor free, nor is there male and female, for you are all one in Christ Jesus. If you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham’s seed, and heirs according to the promise (Galatians 3:28-29 NIV).

In conclusion, "Paul's gospel" was not the only extant gospel to be found in the province of Galatia. There were other gospels making the rounds. Paul needed to make very clear to the Galatian believers that the gospel he was preaching--his gospel--was the genuine article, prompting him to say,

> I am astonished that you are so quickly deserting the one who called you to live in the grace of Christ and are turning to a different gospel—which is really no gospel at all. Evidently some people are throwing you into confusion and are trying to pervert the gospel of Christ. But even if we or an angel from heaven should preach **a gospel other than the one we preached to you**, let them be under God’s curse! As we have already said, so now I say again: If anybody is preaching to you a gospel other than what you accepted, let them be under God’s curse! (1:6-9 NIV, my emphasis).

Comment: (1) Well, you didn't need to lecture me here on the point that the gospel did not belong to Paul, which I am well too aware. The problem here is that given all the points that you've brought up it would have still been even more logical then to say something like "which is what my gospel is about" or "as I preach in my gospel" instead of "according to my gospel". What is primary and what is secondary here? Is it the things done by God or the news of the things done by God? Is it God's deeds or the gospel that preaches God's deeds?

Comment: (2) Of course, the former comes first and the latter comes second. The former is the basis and the latter is based on it. Therefore, at least in English, it would be more natural to say that the latter is "according to" the former, not the other way around. And it is not something that I am overthinking - it was, in fact, my very first reaction when I read those words.

Comment: (3) You would normally say that you’ve given an account of some events exactly according to how they have happened. You wouldn’t say that you’ve given an account of some events and that they were happening "according to your account". I wish you would have considered this question more from linguistic perspective. Perhaps, the usage of Greek preposition κατά (“according to”) is the key here.

Comment: No lecture intended. Of that you may rest assured! Let's just say that Paul had what you might call a "proprietary interest" in the ministry to which God had called him. He knew and felt God's call upon his life, and he was bound and determined to be obedient to that call, whatever the cost. Part of that cost involved at times being at odds with the apostle Peter, whom Paul accused of hypocrisy (see Gal 2:11 ff.). Can you blame Paul for being the way he was? Again, he had a proprietary interest in his gospel and would not brook any opposition to it, as he had received it from Jesus himself.

Comment: Do you mean by "proprietary interest" to say that Paul regarded the gospel entrusted to him by Jesus Himself as coming before all the things that happened to Jesus? For example, do you mean to say that Paul regarded the teaching about the resurrection of Jesus Christ as the source of the very fact of the resurrection of Jesus Christ? If yes, then I'm quite perplexed here. I mean it's absolutely fine to me to say "Jesus was resurrected according to the Scriptures", but I still find it awkward to say "Jesus was resurrected according to the gospel". After all, gospel started after resurrection.

Comment: @brilliant: I'm not following your argument. Forgive me. I did, however, think of a way in which Paul's proprietary interest in his gospel can be understood. If, for example, I have come under the tutelage of a great pianist and piano teacher, whose teaching method is unorthodox but whose students turn out to be fine pianists. One day, a student of a different piano teacher hears me play. Afterward, she takes me to task for my improper technique, saying "That's not how I was taught to play that piece," to which I reply "Well, I was taught by one of the best, and his way is my way."

Comment: I am not arguing with you. I am, on the contrary, trying to understand your point, especially when you have brought this concept of "proprietary interest", which I think I only have started to understand. Your illustration with the pianist is, in fact, quite helpful. Allow me, nevertheless, to confirm whether I understood it correctly. You in your example is apostle Paul. Right? Your teacher is the Lord. Right? The way you play the piece is the gospel. Right? The other pianist who confronted you about your way of playing is someone (like false prophet?) who spreads false gospel. Right? No?

Comment: About the word "argument" . . .. An argument is a line of reasoning or a series of assertions in support of a point of view. In that sense, an argument is NOT an instance of bickering or angry recriminations. It's more of a logic-based discussion. As for your analysis of my analogy, I think you're spot on. Paul received a gift from the Lord--the gospel. Paul did not do anything to deserve it, but once it was given to him he felt an obligation to hew to it as given to him by the Lord. Any significant variance of that gospel was anathema to Paul and to the truth of his (possessive case) gift.

Comment: (1) Sorry, I always get confused when the word "argument" is used because it has more than one meaning. So, when you said you were not following my argument, did you mean that you didn't understand my point or that you were not going to continue a line of reasoning?

Comment: (2) Since I got your analogy right, I would want to draw your attention to the answer you gave to another pianist. You said, "Well, I was taught by one of the best, and his way is my way." Look, you said, "his way is my way". You could've probably also said "my way is according to his way." But most likely you wouldn't say "his way is according to my way" as that, I think, would sound at the very least disrespectful. Do you see my point?

Comment: @brilliant: Yes, I see your point. How do you think your point supports your assertion that the King James Version's translation of "according to my gospel" is unfortunate? By the way, not all English versions translate "according to my gospel." For example, NIV (Rom 2:16): "as my gospel declares" and "This is my gospel" (2 Tim 2:8).  RSV  (2 Tim 2:8): "as preached in my gospel." WYC (Tim): "after my gospel" and (Rom) "after my gospel." Darby: "after my gospel" (Rom) and "according to my glad tidings" (Tim). CEV (Tim): "just as my good news says" and (Rom) "just as my message says."

Comment: (1) I don’t think I’ve made an assertion that the KJV’s translation of this phrase is unfortunate. So far I’ve only expressed my confusion over this translation and suspicion that translation might be too direct.

Comment: (2) How does my point support that? I think it’s very clear and self-explanatory: just as in your answer to the pianist you didn’t dare to say that the way your teacher played the piece was “according to your way”, but said “his way is my way” instead, it would have also been strange, I think, for Paul to say that Jesus had been raised “according to his gospel” – not only because of Paul’s respect toward the Lord, but also simply because of the chronology of things: the resurrection happened first and the gospel came later.

Comment: (3) In fact, the gospel is simply the news of the event of resurrection. Firstly the event takes place and then the news is spread. It is like when we say “the son takes after his father”, not “the father takes after his son”, because a father always comes before his son.

Comment: (4) I think in the original Greek the usage here is looser, that is, the phrase “A is according to B” is absolutely identical to “B is according to A” and the precedence of A over B or B over A is not implied like in English and other languages. In those other versions cited by you the translators must have taken this nuance into their account, but the KJV translators must have decided to stick closer to the original word order in Greek instead.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Good comment:

> Of course, if we take into consideration Paul's attitude throughout all his epistles, we'll see that this is not the case. But then why not say something more humble like "which is what my gospel is about" or "which my gospel corresponds to"?

In fact, this is how I interpret it: "according to my gospel" is a short-hand to mean "which my gospel corresponds to". It is less wordy.

> In the day when God shall judge the secrets of men by **Jesus Christ** according to my gospel. (Rom. 2:16, KJV)

The emphasis here is on "Jesus Christ" not "according to my gospel".

Here is my paraphrased version:

> In the day when God shall judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ because that's what Jesus has told me.

Pulpit Commentary

> My gospel means "the gospel committed unto me to preach"

> Remember that **Jesus Christ** of the seed of David was raised from the dead according to my gospel. (2nd Tim. 2:8, KJV)

Same thing here, the emphasis here is on "Jesus Christ" not "according to my gospel".

The Greek preposition is κατά.
I think the English translation "according to" is a bit too strong and misleading.

English Standard Version

> Remember Jesus Christ, risen from the dead, the offspring of David, **as preached in** my gospel,

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it might mean the Gospel story that Paul told and is included in what Luke wrote?  In Luke 1: 1-4, Luke refers to "us" in the writing of it, and Luke certainly was a companion of Paul.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/49376)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Marlene. However, biblical hermeneutices requires examining the text to find out what the answer to the question is.  You have just asked a question and made a one-sentence comment, but if you care to enlarge on your answer and offer biblical evidences to back up a conclusion , that would be good.